# Updating a large batch of data in a DE without primary keys

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, update, marketingcloudapi

I have an issue with a client, that I would like to know if anyone could help us with some kind of alternative solution. There is a client Data Extension with over 14 million records that we need to update, but it was implemented without having any primary keys.

So far the only solution we came across is using an automation where we backup the data in a staging Data Extension with primary keys so that we can use it to update the data, then we ovewrite the information in the final DE. But this is not something we are very pleased with since there are several other processes that use the same Data Extension and we do not want to disturb any of these processes, also since it has been working for a long time with no primary keys we could potentially lose some information in the process.

I researched a bit and found an API request I can use to update the data as well, but Salesforce sets some best practices to use it and one of them is sending only 50 records at a time, which would not help us either since it would take too much time. (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.htm )

Does anyone know any other thing we could try?

Comment: Duplicate the data extension, overwrite your result to the duplicated DE and then write another query that overwrites your production DE from the duplicated DE with the updated data. That way your production DE is not altered. You need to use SQL for that amount of records but be mindful it may timeout depending on what exactly is being updated and how much processing is required.

Comment: Thanks @thechrishaddad, I was already thinking about doing that. I wanted to know if there were any other options.